# Why I get this error when use conda install llvmlite?

Tags: python, conda

When I use conda install llvmlite, I got this error:

```
zs@guo-Lenovo:~$ conda install llvmlite


Fetching packages ...
Error: Could not open u'/home/zs/miniconda/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2d-     0.tar.bz2.part' for writing (seek).                          | ETA:  --:--:--   0.00  B/s
```

Any idea to avoid this problem?

Comment: What version of conda are you using? try `conda update conda`, `conda update anaconda`.

Comment: thank you for your help!the version of conda is 3.16.0,and I try "conda update conda"     but it can not work either ，has the same error as run "conda install llvmlite"